# Convergence (rate) of a three term recurrence

Tags: analysis, optimization, asymptotics, upper-lower-bounds

Suppose we have following recurrence relation for a positive real sequence $\{a_n\}$
\begin{align*}
a_{n+1} \le \left(q+\frac {c_1} {n+1}\right) a_n + \frac{c_2}{n} a_{n-1},
\end{align*}
where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are some positive constants and $0 < q < 1$. Will the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ stay bounded (or better, converging to $0$)?

My intuition is: since there are only finitely many $n$ with $q+c_1/(n+1) > 1$, eventually the sequence will decrease and so converge to $0$. But I haven't come up a rigorous proof. I did some simulation by making the inequality to be equality, it seems like the sequence converges to $0$ even with $q=0.999$.

---

UPDATE:

Thanks to @Michael. I got one solution which is based on the observation pointed out by @Michael. He also gave another way to proceed based on this observation (see his answer.)

We observe for every $1 > r >0$, for sufficiently large $n$, the recurrence is equivalent to
\begin{align*}
a_{n+1} \le \frac{1+q}{2} a_n + r a_{n-1}.
\end{align*}
Without loss of generality, we may assume for all $n$, above relation holds. Now if we can find some parameters $0<q'<1$ and $c >0$ such that
\begin{align*}
a_{n+1} + c a_n \le q'(a_n + c a_{n-1}),
\end{align*}
it is clear $a_n \to 0$ since the sequence is positive. One choice is putting $q' = \frac{3+q} 4$ and $c=\frac{1-q} 4$. In this case, we can take $r = \frac{(1-q)(3+q)} {16}$.

---

The remaining question is whether it is possible to estimate the rate of convergence. Any comments are welcome. Thanks.

---

UPDATE on convergence rate:
@Michael pointed out some convergence rate when $c_1, c_2$ are sufficiently small. I think if using my method, we could give a convergence rate related to $\varepsilon > 0$.

For any $1-q>\varepsilon >0$, there exists $N$ such that $n \ge N$, 
\begin{align*}
a_{n+1} + c a_n \le (q+ \varepsilon) (a_n + c a_{n-1}).
\end{align*}
Let $N'$ be the smallest integer such that $c_1/N' \le \varepsilon$ and $M = \max_{j \le N'} (a_j + c a_{j-1})$.
Then $a_{n+1} \le a_{n+1} + ca_n \le (q+\varepsilon)^{n-N'} M$. Looks like some pseudo linear rate.

Could we do better? Any comments will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Your intuition is correct, $a_n\rightarrow 0$ regardless of the initial conditions (assumign $a_n \geq 0$ for all $n$).  You can perhaps prove it by noticing that $$ a_{n+1} \leq \frac{(1+q)}{2}a_n + \frac{(1-q)}{4} a_{n-1} $$ for all sufficiently large $n$.

Comment: @Michael: Thanks for your comment. I can see the relation reduces to the one you pointed out. To continue, my thought is to find some $q'$ and $c$ such that $a_{n+1}+ca_n \le q'(a_n + c a_{n-1})$. This holds if $q' c = (1-q)/4$ and $q'-c=(1+q)/2$. But I could not see the proper choice for $q'$ and $c$. Or the direction is not correct. Could you elaborate your comment. Thanks.

Comment: That is also a good way.  To do that, you can modify my above comment to say that for any arbitrarily small $r>0$ we have (for all sufficiently large $n$)  $$ a_{n+1} \leq \frac{(1+q)}{2}a_n + r a_{n-1}$$  Then you can design $c>0, r>0, q'>0$ so that your inequality holds (you will likely want $q' < 1$).

Comment: @Michael: I see, thanks. You mentioned 'also'. Is there some other method? I would appreciate it if you could share your thoughts.

Comment: I suggested using $r$ since it gives you some more freedom to solve your way.  I was thinking in terms of $a_{n+1} \leq \alpha a_n + \beta a_{n-1}$ where $\alpha>0, \beta >0$ and $\alpha + \beta < 1$. So intuitively the right-hand-side is strictly less than a convex combination of $a_n$ and $a_{n-1}$.

Comment: @Michael: Please forgive my slowness. I don't see how to proceed with your method. Suppose we have chosen $\alpha, \beta$ with $\alpha + \beta < 1$, then putting $b = \max\{a_n, a_{n-1}\}$,  $a_{n+1} \le \alpha a_n + \beta a_{n-1} \le \alpha b + \beta b < b$. It seems like this can only guarantee $\liminf a_n = 0$.

Comment: Let me see.  Can it be shown that $\max[a_{n+2}, a_{n+1}] \leq \rho \max[a_{n}, a_{n-1}]$ for some $\rho<1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose there is an integer $M>0$, constants $\alpha \geq 0, \beta \geq 0$ that satisfy $\alpha + \beta < 1$, and a nonnegative sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that 
$$  a_{n+1} \leq \alpha a_n + \beta a_{n-1} \quad, \forall n \geq M $$
Then $a_n \rightarrow 0$.

Proof step 1: Define $\rho = \alpha + \beta$ and note that $0 \leq \rho < 1$. Then for all $n \geq M$ show that 
$$ a_{n+1} \leq \rho \max[a_n, a_{n-1}]$$
Proof step 2: Show that for all $n \geq M$:
$$ a_{n+2} \leq \rho \max[a_n, a_{n-1}]$$
Thus 
$$ \max[a_{n+2}, a_{n+1}] \leq \rho \max[a_n, a_{n-1}] \quad, \forall n \geq M$$
$\Box$

---

Here is a proof that $a_n \leq A(n+1) q^n$ for all $n \in\{1, 2, 3, ...\}$ whenever it holds for $a_1$ and $a_2$, and when $c_1, c_2$ are sufficiently small to ensure $c_1/q + c_2/q^2 \leq 1$.

Claim: Let $q,c_1,c_2, A$ be positive constants. Suppose $c_1/q + c_2/q^2 \leq 1$.  If $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of nonnegative numbers such that 
$$a_{n+1} \leq (q + c_1/(n+1))a_n + (c_2/n)a_{n-1} \quad, \forall n \in\{2, 3, 4, ...\} \quad \mbox{(Eq. *)}$$ 
and if $a_i \leq A(i+1)q^i$ for $i \in\{1, 2, ..., m\}$ (for some integer $m\geq 2$), then it also holds for $i=m+1$, that is, $a_{m+1} \leq A(m+2)q^{m+1}$.

Proof:
\begin{align}
a_{m+1} &\leq (q + c_1/(m+1))a_m + (c_2/m)a_{m-1}\\
&\leq (q + c_1/(m+1))A(m+1)q^m + (c_2/m)Amq^{m-1}\\
&=A(m+2)q^{m+1}\underbrace{\left[\frac{(m+1) + c_1/q + c_2/q^2}{m+2}\right]}_{\leq 1} \\
&\leq A(m+2)q^{m+1}
\end{align}
$\Box$

---

For $q>0$ and general $c_1, c_2 \geq 0$, define 
$$ b = \max\left[1, \frac{c_1}{q} + \frac{c_2}{q^2}\right]$$
Assume $\{a_n\}$ satisfies (Eq *). 
Define $A\geq 0$ large enough so that $a_1 \leq A (1+1)^bq$ and $a_2 \leq A(2+1)^bq^2$.

Claim:  $a_n \leq A(n+1)^b q^n$ for all $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$.

Proof: It holds by assumption for $n=1, n=2$.  Suppose it holds for an integer $n\geq 2$.  We show it also holds for $n+1$.

\begin{align}
a_{n+1} &\overset{(a)}{\leq} (q + c_1/(n+1))a_n + (c_2/n)a_{n-1} \\
&\overset{(b)}{\leq} (q + c_1/(n+1))A(n+1)^bq^n + (c_2/n)An^bq^{n-1}\\
&= A(n+1)^bq^{n+1} + Ac_1(n+1)^{b-1} q^n + Ac_2n^{b-1}q^{n-1}\\
&= Aq^{n+1}\left[(n+1)^b + \frac{c_1}{q}(n+1)^{b-1} + \frac{c_2}{q^2}n^{b-1}\right]\\
&\leq  Aq^{n+1}\left[(n+1)^b + \left(\frac{c_1}{q} + \frac{c_2}{q^2}\right)(n+1)^{b-1}\right]\\
&\overset{(c)}{\leq} Aq^{n+1}\left[(n+1)^b + b(n+1)^{b-1}\right]\\
&\overset{(d)}\leq Aq^{n+1}(n+2)^b
\end{align}
where (a) holds by (Eq. *); (b) holds by the induction hypothesis; (c) holds by definition of $b$; (d) holds by convexity of the function $f(x)=(n+1+x)^b$ for $x\geq 0$, so that 
$$ \underbrace{f(1)}_{(n+2)^b} \geq \underbrace{f(0) + f'(0)(1-0)}_{(n+1)^b + b(n+1)^{b-1}} $$
$\Box$

Comment: Thanks. I believe I can prove this statement. A follow up question: is it possible to estimate the convergence rate of this sequence?

Comment: The last inequality shows it decreases exponentially fast: Taken in pairs, the max over each successive pair decays like $\rho^k$.  But since $a_{n+1} \approx q a_n$ for your inequality and for large $n$, I would expect the decrease to be close to $q^n$ (a better bound).

Comment: Thanks for your amazing answer. In my case, I have no control of $c_1$ and $c_2$. Indeed, $c_1, c_2 >1$ are more likely. Could you comment this case? Is $\rho^k$ the best we can do? Thanks.

Comment: The case of general $c_1, c_2$ can be solved by using $a_n \leq A(n+1)^b q^n$ for sufficiently large $b$.  What is this particular problem for?

Comment: Please take a look at my update. This actually comes from my research. I came up some algorithm and after some manipulations, the algorithm reduces to the problem posted. Since we have established the convergence, the rate will be very helpful for me. Thanks.

Comment: I updated some details on the $A(n+1)^bq^n$ idea. I wonder what algorithm setting this relates to?

Comment: This is related to a distributed convex problem I am working on recently. Thanks for your useful answer and comments.

Comment: Another question: comparing the convergence rate you derived and the one I mentioned in the post, which one is better? I understand your rate is better in the sense it does not depend on some unknown parameter. But the $(n+1)$ bugs me a little bit. If $q$ is very close to $1$, this means probably many (say the first $10^4$) iterations will not make any progress.

Comment: Well, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{(n+1)^b q^n}{(q+\epsilon)^n}=0$ for any $\epsilon>0$, so $(n+1)^bq^n$ has better asymptotics.  But you are right it might increase at first for small $n$.  Of course, I would not expect any progress until $n$ is large enough to ensure $q+c_1/(n+1) + c_2/n \leq 1$, since then it is like taking convex combinations of $a_n, a_{n-1}$ and then scaling by $\rho$.  Also, you can make the bound $\min[A (n+1)^b q^n, g_n]$ where $g_n$ is from some other upper bound, like from  $\max[a_{n+2},a_n]\leq \rho \max[a_n,a_{n-1}]$ or your other.

Comment: Thanks again for your illuminating comments.